# Why do alkylarenes react with alkaline KMnO4, but not benzene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, organic-oxidation

Benzene($\ce{C6H6}$) does not react with alkaline $\ce{KMnO4}$, however alkylarenes react when there are benzylic hydrogens. What could be the reason for this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Benzene does not have any benzylic hydrogen it's formula is C6H6 while alkyl arenes 1 degree or 2 degree have benzylic H atoms which get oxidized in presence of strong oxidizing agents like alkaline KMnO4

The mechanism given in this [link](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/reaction-guide/oxidation-of-aromatic-alkanes-with-kmno4-to-give-carboxylic-acids/) is as follows.

[image]